# Ubuntu 20.04 Wifi not connecting automatically

Tags: wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a new PC and using wifi dongle (https://www.amazon.in/Live-Tech-Nano-Wirless-Adapter/dp/B078SSXTG7) to connect to wifi. I have saved the passwords, but every time on starting Ubuntu, I have to manually connect to the wifi network and provide password. It does not automatically connect. Moreover, when I got to wifi setting under visible networks I see several duplicate entries for my wifi - one for each time I have given the password. Can someone please help me in this. If any more information is needed, please let me know.

output of sudo lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04ca:0061 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

output of sudo lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4c43 (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 4c8a (rev 04)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 4c11 (rev 01)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 43ed (rev 11)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 43ef (rev 11)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 43e0 (rev 11)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 43d2 (rev 11)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 43bc (rev 11)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4387 (rev 11)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 43c8 (rev 11)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 43a3 (rev 11)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 43a4 (rev 11)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (10) I219-V (rev 11)
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Kingston Technology Company, Inc. Device 500f (rev 03)
```

output of sudo lshw -c network

```
 *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (10) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno1
       version: 11
       serial: d8:bb:c1:64:2b:ae
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.11.0-43-generic firmware=0.6-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:122 memory:92200000-9221ffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:7
       logical name: wlx82316482c99f
       serial: 82:31:64:82:c9:9f
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu driverversion=5.11.0-43-generic ip=192.168.29.132 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Comment: Do you have multiple WiFi devices connected to the machine? Could you [edit] your question to include the terminal output of: (0) `sudo lsusb` (1) `sudo lspci` and (2) `sudo lshw -c network`? This will show some information about your hardware and network.

Comment: If this is for a single wifi router and not a network of multiple routers, have you tried setting the BSSID? Also, under the "general" tab of your network settings, is it set to automatically connect when this network is available?

Comment: Often times when this happens to me (when it asks for a new password). I simply exit the popup and then disable and enable WIFI on NetworkManager. Usually, I'm able to select the network and/or automatically connect.

Comment: @mchid i am able to connect to a given BSSID using password from the terminal. But I am looking for system to automatically connect to the wifi. The setting for connect automatically is ticked and Password is also saved and correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatically connecting to wi-fi through built-in method is still not working for some reason. I have found an alternative way to connect to wifi at startup(with a known BSSID as mentioned by @mchid above).

To get BSSID for your wifi please refer below question.

[Getting BSSID and connecting to it is referred to from here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833905/how-can-i-connect-to-a-specific-bssid)

```
nmcli -f in-use,ssid,bssid,signal,bars  dev wifi
```

Once you get the BSSID from above create a shell script connect.sh with below text

```
#!/bin/bash
nmcli d wifi connect xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx password "yourpassword"
```

replace xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx with your BSSID.
save the file and change the file permission to make it executable

```
chmod +x connect.sh
```

In Ubuntu 20.04 there is an application "startup applications" that can be accessed from the GUI. add the above script file in startup application and now it connects automatically on startup.